# Last values sent down the channel cannot be received in main goroutine Golang

Tags: macos, go, concurrency

Given TCP port scanner in golang. 2 implementations, the 1st is mine and the 2nd is from golang book. Supposed the 2nd one is 100% workable as tested before by many readers. But seemed both have the same problem: last value that is sent down the **results** channel cannot be received **in main goroutine**, it gets stuck in infinite awaiting for the value from the channel, despite the fact that the value actually was sent.
Some observations: when amount of ports is less than 21 it works as expected; when amount is more than 1000, the amount of not received values increased to about 10.
I can't understand the reason why.

implementation from book

```
func worker(ports, results chan int) {
    for p := range ports {
        address := fmt.Sprintf("scanme.nmap.org:%d", p)
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            results <- 0
            fmt.Println("sent", p)
            continue
        }
        conn.Close()
        results <- p
        fmt.Println("sent", p)
    }
}

func main() {
    ports := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan int)

    var openports []int

    for i := 0; i < cap(ports); i++ {
        go worker(ports, results)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= 50; i++ {
            ports <- i
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        port := <-results // after 49 it gets stuck infinitely, never proceed further
        fmt.Println("received", port, i)
        if port != 0 {
            openports = append(openports, port)
        }
    }

    close(ports)
    close(results)

    sort.Ints(openports)

    fmt.Println(openports)

}
```

Comment: Try a [simplified example](https://go.dev/play/p/3J-J5xl2Lqb). I suspect the issue is not what you expect. `for i := 0; i < 50; i++` means `i` will never reach `50`. When sending the work you loop `i := 1; i <= 50; i++` i.e. `i` starts at 1 and runs to 50, when receiving `i` starts at 0 and runs to 49.

Comment: "when amount is more than 1000" I feel like you're probably hitting ulimit issues at this point.

Comment: @Brits To clarify, `i` will [indeed](https://go.dev/play/p/IK2bFdglo0N) reach `50`, which is necessary for the loop to end; there just won't be an iteration associated to `50`.

Comment: @Brits, last loop is needed just to get results, and 0..50 does 50 iterations as supposed. But it's a good simplify example: now I can say that 
func worker(ports, results chan int) {
    for p := range ports {
        results <- p
    }
}
works correctly! so the problem with net.Dial I guess

Comment: @flakes no; in this case, just as the range of ports to scan is growing, the number of troublesome ports is increasing. Dial hangs on them preventing main goroutine from getting results and moving further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by adding timeout to net.Dialer

```
    func worker(ports, results chan int) {
    dialer := net.Dialer{Timeout: time.Second}

    for p := range ports {
        address := fmt.Sprintf("scanme.nmap.org:%d", p)
        conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            results <- 0
            continue
        }

        conn.Close()
        results <- p
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a timeout cannot be the correct solution to your problem. Instead, your `main` function should range over the `results` channel, which you should close as soon as you know all results have been sent on it (hint: use a wait group).

Comment: it's just a snippet to highlight changes. Ofc it does iterating over results channel in main and close it at the end. Timeout just doesn't allow Dial method to hang on scanning individual ports infinitely making programme freeze while waiting for results. In short, it skips "problematic" ports, considering them blocked or closed.